# How to set the cache size of the ListView of Flutter?

Tags: listview, caching, flutter

I am using `ListView` in flutter. I want to set the pre-fetch size of `ListView`. Is there any method to do that?

For example, even though user didn't scroll the items to the index of 50, I want `ListView` to pre-fetch the list of index 1 to 50.

Comment: I don't see how this would be related to `ListView`. You don't need support in the widget if you want to fetch data from the server.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for your reply. I realized that this is not related to `ListView`. It was a silly question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cacheExtent parameter in ListView.